# Root interface property not accessible via parent interface in Html helper

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I feel like I am missing something basic here.

I have 2 interfaces. One is called IIdentifiable which specifies the existence of an Id property. The second can really be anything that is also identifiable. See code below.

```
public interface IIdentifiable
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
}
public interface IPerson : IIdentifiable
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**The problem:**

When using the Html.HiddenFor (or any other helper method) and the model is strongly typed to the IPerson interface, I get an error when accessing the properties of the IIdentifiable interface. I can access and display the data in the IIdentifiable properties by going directly against Model.Id but not when using the lambda expression and accessing the model that way.

The error I get is "The property *.IPerson.Id could not be found".

This only seems to be the case when using the Razor view engine. I know this was working using ASP.NET MVC 2 and the WebForms view engine. I haven't tried it on the ASP.NET MVC 3 using the WebForms view engine yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [I have brought this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/636341/modelmetadata-fromlambdaexpression-has-changed-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rtm) to the attention of Microsoft by opening a ticket. Also see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702483/asp-net-mvc-3-htmlhelper-exception-does-not-recognize-modelmetadata-on-inherited/4702788).

Comment: Thanks! I searched SO for these but never came across them. I was going to dive into the source today if I didn't get an answer. Appreciate it. Now lets hope Microsoft addresses he issue.

Answer (score 0):

I always feel less insane when other people have the same problems I do. As someone said in the link Darin provided, this is a work around or now:

```
<%: Html.HiddenFor(m => (m as IIdentifiable).Id) %>
```