# Accessing a generic collection from view model in html helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm attempting to write an html helper in which I want to iterate over a known typed property which is a generic list, and output the required HTML content. Here is an outline of how I have constructed the view model to ensure any view models comply with the helper;

**Interface definition:**

```
public Interface ITheViewModelInterface<T> where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**Concrete abstract interface implementation** (so that I can define default values) :

```
public abstract class TheConcreteViewModelImplementation<T> : IViewModelInterface<T> where T : class
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class TheViewModel : TheConcreteViewModelImplementation<MyListType>
{ 

}
```

What would be the helper definition such that I could access the correctly typed list of items in the base class? I'm not entirely sure I need a strongly typed helper in this instance, but how do I explicitly pass the items type in the helper call?

Comment: Have you looked into using [Display Templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) instead?

Comment: @levelnis, No I haven't looked at display templates in any depth. Do you think this method would be better suited to my requirements?

Comment: I think it could be quite a good fit. You would need to create a template with the same name as the type it represents (e.g. `MyListType.cshtml`) within `Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates` and then call `Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Items)` to render your items out.

Comment: Mmm... ok, I'll take a look in more depth. I was rather hoping to access the entire Model though as I need other properties. Would this possible with display templates?

Comment: Certainly is - you can use `Html.DisplayForModel()` and create templates (or use the default ones in the framework) for each data type contained within your model. Have a look at part 4 of Brad's series - it gives a good explanation of customising the default object template

Comment: Sounds interesting. I'll take a further look and report back. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research on this matter, I found this discussion which provides some answers (and a rather astounding statement from Microsoft!) to my question;

[ASP.NET MVC 3 HtmlHelper Exception does not recognize ModelMetadata on inherited interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702483/asp-net-mvc-3-htmlhelper-exception-does-not-recognize-modelmetadata-on-inherited/15806809#15806809)